# Vue: Reset data object to original value after API call has failed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue component which fetches data from a remote API passing it to a child component. When the user clicks a button, the API is called to submit the data. The API returns the updated data object and updates the component with the new data. So far, so good.

But I'm struggling for the error case. If the API call is not successful, I need to "reset" the `apiData` object to the initial state as received in the `mounted()` function. Otherwise the user would still see the values she changed but which actually failed to update.

Two apporaches come to my mind:

1. Refresh the data from the API for the error case
2. Copy the originally received data to a variable which then will be re-assigned in the error case

Or maybe there is some more "Vue-ish" way to achieve this?

```js
<template>
    <some-component v-model="apiData"></some-component>
</template>
data() {
    return {        
        apiData: {}
    }
},
mounted() {
   this.apiData = ApiService.getData();
},
methods: {
    async onSubmit() {
        try {
            const response = await ApiService.update(this.apiData);
            this.apiData = response.data;
        } catch (e) {
            showErrorNotification();
            // How to reset `apiData` to the initial state as in mounted() ???
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second solution sounds logical and simple. I'd go with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API gets an error and does not return us any new results.
If it doesn't return new results, we still have our old data (the data you want)
Aren't we waiting for this?
If so, what's the problem for us?

Comment: The data changes because it's passed to another component as `v-model`.

Comment: Sometimes one can't see the forest from the trees. After having read your answer I actually realized: It's perfectly fine the way it is. The API returns an error and the `v-model` doesn't change. That's what I, as a user, would expect.

Comment: Does it currently work well for you?